# Export value after axios call response using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need one solution. I am using `axios` module to fetch response from other server and after that I need to export value to other file using Node.js. I am explaining my code below.

```
const axios = require('axios');
let protocol = '';
let opticalIp = '';


axios.get(`www.mydomain.com/api`).then(function(response) {
    //console.log('succ', response);
    if(response.data && response.data.data) {
        protocol = response.data.data['scheme'];
        opticalIp = response.data.data['optical_ip'];
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('error', error);
});
console.log('data', opticalIp);

const env = {
    API_URL: `${protocol}://${opticalIp}/`,
    configHeaders: ''
};
  
module.exports = env;
```

Here I am fetching the data from other server and also here I am returning some `env` value to other file. In my case before response the `env` object is returning so that the `API_URL` value is going blank. Here I need after the success response the `API_URL` will be prepared and then this `env` object should return to other file where ever it is called. Please help me to get the proper solution.

Comment: Unless you are using an environment that supports top level `await` for exports, you cannot export a value you obtained asynchronously because exports happen synchronously BEFORE the asynchronous value is available.  The typical work-around is to export a function that can be called that will retrieve the value asynchronously and the caller uses asynchronous techniques (promise or callback) to access the asynchronously retrieved value.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you'll want to just export a function that you can call from the other file. This will avoid quite a bit of headache later on. Since axios returns a promise (hence the .then()) call after the request, you can just return the axios request call and modify whichever value you'd like to return from within the .then() call.

[Here's an overview of promise chaining provided by javascript.info](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining).

```js
// CHILD MODULE

const axios = require('axios');

function fetchOptical () {
  let protocol = '';
  let opticalIp = '';
  
  return axios.get(`https://10.0.12.17:9201/api/v1.0/settings/custom-form/Optical`)
    .then(function(response) {
      //console.log('succ', response);
      if(response.data && response.data.data) {
          protocol = response.data.data['scheme'];
          opticalIp = response.data.data['optical_ip'];
          const env = {
            API_URL: `${protocol}://${opticalIp}/`,
            configHeaders: ''
          };
          
          console.log('data', opticalIp);
          return env
      }
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('error', error);
        return error
    });
  })
}

module.exports = fetchOptical;
```

```js
// PARENT MODULE

import child from './child'

child().then(env => {

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying `protocol` and `opticalIp` will not change `API_URL`. Instead, in the `then`, try:

```
if(response.data && response.data.data) {
    const protocol = response.data.data['scheme'];
    const opticalIp = response.data.data['optical_ip'];
    env.API_URL = `${protocol}://${opticalIp}/`;
}

// Then when defining env:

const env = {
    API_URL: null, // null or '' or whatever you want the default to be.
    configHeaders: ''
};
```